# Change two values depending on specific comparisons between two other values?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, variables, comparison

I am making a small game and I have two variables; one for the player's choice and another for the computer's random choice.
The player can choose between attack1, attack2, and attack3. And so will the computer (using Math.random()).

I want to increase the score of the winner if they choose an option that beats the computer's option. And increase the number of draws if they choose the same.

I have written an if-else statement that accomplishes this but I think it should be possible to make it shorter or better.
Let's call the attacks rock, paper, and scissors so it's easy to see who would win:

THE WHOLE JS CODE IS IN THE CODE SNIPPET AND JSFiddle

```
    if (playerChoice === computerChoice) {
        draw++;
    } else if (playerScore === rock && computerChoice === scissors) {
        playerScore++;
    } else if (playerScore === paper && computerChoice === rock) {
        playerScore++;
    } else if (playerChoice === scissors && computerChoice === paper) {
        playerScore++;
    } else {
        computerScore++;
    }
```

I am using a function to check if any of the three statements are true, and if so the player's score should increase, and if not the computer's score should increase.

JDFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lowxc31b/

Snippet:

```js
var playerScore = 0;
var computerScore = 0;
var draw = 0;
var possibleChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

var playerScoreEl = document.getElementById("playerScore");
var computerScoreEl = document.getElementById("computerScore");
var drawEl = document.getElementById("draw");
var rockEl = document.getElementById("rock");
var paperEl = document.getElementById("paper");
var scissorsEl = document.getElementById("scissors");

var buttonsEl = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < buttonsEl.length; i++) {
  buttonsEl[i].addEventListener("click", checkResult);
}

function checkResult(e) {
  var playerChoice = e.target.id;
  var randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  var computerChoice = possibleChoices[randomChoice];

  if (playerChoice === computerChoice) {
    draw++;
  } else if (playerChoice === rockEl.id && computerChoice === "scissors") {
    playerScore++;
  } else if (playerChoice === paperEl.id && computerChoice === "rock") {
    playerScore++;
  } else if (playerChoice === scissorsEl.id && computerChoice === "paper") {
    playerScore++;
  } else {
    computerScore++;
  }
  playerScoreEl.innerHTML = playerScore;
  computerScoreEl.innerHTML = computerScore;
  drawEl.innerHTML = draw;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  font-size: 21px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

#button {
  margin: 10px;
}

#wrapping {
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}

#rock,
#paper,
#scissors {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="no">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Rock paper scissors</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapping">
    <b>Player: </b>
    <p id="playerScore"> 0 </p> <br>
    <b>Computer: </b>
    <p id="computerScore"> 0 </p> <br>
    <b>Draw's: </b>
    <p id="draw"> 0 </p> <br>
    <div id="buttons">
      <button id="rock" class="button"> Rock </button>
      <button id="paper" class="button"> Paper </button>
      <button id="scissors" class="button"> Scissors </button>
    </div>
    <p id="info"> </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, AcidNick. You've posted working code that is about as concise as I could imagine would be useful (aside from insane tricks I've seen done for hackathons) - the goal for most code is to be readable and maintainable - which is what I see here. If you are facing an issue due to script size, I think you should look into tools that perform script minification. Without more detail on why you need it more consise (what problem are you trying to actually solve) that is all I can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could turn the choices into *numbers alone*, and then just check whether the difference between the computer's and the player's, modulo 3, is 0, 1, or 2:

```
  var playerChoice = Number(e.target.id); // could also remove the IDs entirely
        // and check the child element index among its siblings
  var computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  // Need to add 3 so that negative results get %d properly:
  const diff = (playerChoice - computerChoice + 3) % 3;
  if (diff === 0) {
    draw++;
  } else if (diff === 1) {
    playerScore++;
  } else {
    computerScore++;
  }
```

```js
var playerScore = 0;
var computerScore = 0;
var draw = 0;
var possibleChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

var playerScoreEl = document.getElementById("playerScore");
var computerScoreEl = document.getElementById("computerScore");
var drawEl = document.getElementById("draw");
var rockEl = document.getElementById("rock");
var paperEl = document.getElementById("paper");
var scissorsEl = document.getElementById("scissors");

var buttonsEl = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < buttonsEl.length; i++) {
  buttonsEl[i].addEventListener("click", checkResult);
}

const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
function checkResult(e) {
  var playerChoice = Number(e.target.id);
  var computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  console.log('Player played', choices[playerChoice], 'Computer played', choices[computerChoice]);
  const diff = (playerChoice - computerChoice + 3) % 3;
  if (diff === 0) {
    draw++;
  } else if (diff === 1) {
    playerScore++;
  } else {
    computerScore++;
  }
  playerScoreEl.innerHTML = playerScore;
  computerScoreEl.innerHTML = computerScore;
  drawEl.innerHTML = draw;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  font-size: 21px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

#button {
  margin: 10px;
}

#wrapping {
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}

#rock,
#paper,
#scissors {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="no">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Rock paper scissors</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapping">
    <b>Player: </b>
    <p id="playerScore"> 0 </p> <br>
    <b>Computer: </b>
    <p id="computerScore"> 0 </p> <br>
    <b>Draw's: </b>
    <p id="draw"> 0 </p> <br>
    <div id="buttons">
      <button id="0" class="button"> Rock </button>
      <button id="1" class="button"> Paper </button>
      <button id="2" class="button"> Scissors </button>
    </div>
    <p id="info"> </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a very creative way to solve the problem I had, just what I was looking for. Would this also work if the [choices] were in another order? Like ["rock", "scissors", "paper"] ?

Comment: The `choices` array is there just to be able to translate the numbers into words. But the numbers' order needs to combined with the modulo logic properly, so if you change the number order, you'll have to change the modulo logic too.